# I want to update the trustpolicy of existing IAM role using AWS CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I want to update the trust policy of an existing IAM role using AWS CDK.
But I am not finding the exact cdk property to do it.
Please help me.

Lets say
Rolename **my_rolename_1**
with below trust policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::12345:role/role_1"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to add another aws account to trust policy
arn:aws:iam::23451:role/role_2

The trust policy of IAM role should get updated with

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::12345:role/role_1",
                    "arn:aws:iam::23451:role/role_2"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to import the role using below command

```
const Existingrole = iam.Role.fromRoleArn(this, 'Role', 'arn:aws:iam::11111:role/my_rolename_1',{
        mutable: true,
     });
```

But couldn't find exact property to attach/update trustpolicy with new cross account details.

Answer (score 1):

The CDK cannot modify existing, external resources.  The reference returned from the `fromRoleArn` method is [read-only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_external).

The CDK CLI does have an actual (experimental) [cdk import](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/aws-cdk/README.md#cdk-import) capability to bring existing resources into a CDK app.  `AWS::IAM::Role` is a resource type that is [supported for importing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html).  After you import the role, you can modify it like other CDK resources.  Or, instead of importing, you could simply create a new role and delete the existing role.